# Shortest way to convert string from a list to double list

Tags: c#, list

I want to convert string values from a list to double. So that I am using following code

```
List<double> valList = new List<double>();
valList = aList.Select(x => double.TryParse(x.aDoubleValue_inString, out x)? x: 0).ToList();
```

For some reason, its not working, showing me error on usage of double.TryParse!

any idea?

Comment: And what's the error you're seeing?

Comment: x is your object that has some property named aDoubleValue_inString on it. It can't also be an out parameter to TryParse. That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for something like:

```
valList = aList.Select(x=> 
           { 
              double temp; 
              return double.TryParse(x.aDoubleValue_inString, out temp)? temp: 0;
           }).ToList();
```

You can do the similar with [query expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx) like:

```
double temp = 0;
valList = (from x in aList
           where double.TryParse(x.aDoubleValue_inString, out temp)
           select temp).ToList();
```

If your property `x.aDoubleValue_inString` is a double value for sure and you don't need `double.TryParse` then you can do:

```
valList = aList.Select(x=> double.Parse(x.aDoubleValue_inString))
               .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your are trying to make double.TryParse output back to your string list variable. Try:

```
List<double> valList = new List<double>();
double y;
valList = aList.Select(x => double.TryParse(x.aDoubleValue_inString, out y)? y: 0).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `out` doesn't make much sense as-is. This works:

```
var aList = new List<string> { "1.2", "2" };
List<double> valList = new List<double>();
double temp;
valList = aList.Select(x => double.TryParse(x, out temp) ? temp : 0).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not so easy to use methods with `out` parameter in Linq like that without declaring a variable for the `out` parameter outside the Linq itself.

However, I note that you seem to want to replace failed parses with zero, in which case you can write a small helper method like so:

```
static double ParseOrZero(string input)
{
    double result;
    double.TryParse(input, out result);
    return result;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
var valList = aList.Select(ParseOrZero).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it up in a nice extension method

```
public static class StrExt
{
    public static double ToDouble(this string str)
    {
        double val;
        return Double.TryParse(str, out val) ? val : default(Double);
    }
}
...
valList = aList.Select(x => x.aDoubleValue_inString.ToDouble());
```